# Why didn't Gordon Shumway mind being called "ALF"?

Tags: plot-explanation, sitcoms, alf

Considering how acerbic and sarcastic he is, how come Gordon Shumway was so good-natured with the Tanners calling him "ALF"?

If, say, a human went to the planet Melmac and had to hide out in a house, wouldn't that be equivalent to you being called "Human" (or some other silly acronym) all the time?

Comment: No source for this, hence the comment and not answer.  Being given a nickname even one such as "ALF" represents some level of acceptance into the community the Tanners family represents.  Hence, the gesture of the nickname is what is appreciated more than the name itself